# How to print out a specific column from CSV using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Below are the codes I refer from internet, it works perfectly just that may I know how would it be able to print out the specific column from a CSV file? Since the output will only print out predicted and expected price, I want to add the Date column from the CSV file too, just want to make it become tidier. But I couldn't figure it out. Thanks in advance!

*Refer to below the code block for a further explanation.

```
from pandas import read_csv
from numpy import mean
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
from matplotlib import pyplot
import csv


col_list = ["Date", "Close"]
series = read_csv(r'C:\Users\Jane\Downloads\archive\Uniqlo_stock_price.csv', header=0, index_col=0, usecols=col_list)

X = series.values
window = 3
history = [X[i] for i in range(window)]
test = [X[i] for i in range(window, len(X))]
predictions = list()

for t in range(len(test)):
    length = len(history)
    yhat = mean([history[i] for i in range(length - window, length)])
    obs = test[t]
    predictions.append(yhat)
    history.append(obs)
    print('predicted=%.2f, expected=%.2f' % (yhat, obs))
error = mean_squared_error(test, predictions)
print('Test MSE: %.3f' % error)
```

The CSV file:

```
Date        Expected
4/1/2016    42660.00
5/1/2016    41830.00
```

Current output:

```
predicted=43410.00, expected=42660.00
predicted=43183.33, expected=41830.00
```

How I will be able to make it like this, the date from the csv:

```
04/1/2016, predicted=43410.00, expected=42660.00
05/1/2016, predicted=43183.33, expected=41830.00
```

Comment: Where are your `date` stored that you want to include in prediction output ?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the dates are stored in `test['Date']` column

```
dates = test['Date'].values.tolist()

for t in range(len(test)):
    length = len(history)
    yhat = mean([history[i] for i in range(length - window, length)])
    obs = test[t]
    predictions.append(yhat)
    history.append(obs)
    a = dates[t]
    print('Date =', a, 'predicted =', yhat, 'expected =', obs)
```

Comment: Hi Adarsh Wase, thanks for your reply! Well the 'predicted' and 'expected' are actually calculated values that proceed through the code above. So, maybe more precisely, in this row of code`` print('predicted=%.2f, expected=%.2f' % (yhat, obs))``, what can I do so I will be able to print the column I wanted from the csv? Still appreciate your reply!!

Comment: I have edited my answer, please let me know if that helps.

Comment: If it doesn't help, please tell me where are these `Date` stored ?

Comment: Hi Adarsh Wase, thanks again for your reply. I tried the method you mentioned. However now it shows a error saying "TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str" which happened at "dates = test['Date'].values.tolist()". I also updated my question, these Date are stored in the csv file. I believe the code should look like this "test = [X[i] for i in range(window, len(X))]", just couldn't figure it out how to modify LOL.